# Compound SQL Join?

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to construct a SQL query that I think requires multiple JOIN's, but I don't know the syntax.

Here is a rough example of the Tables (with column names) for each.

T1 (key, name)

T2 (key, fkeyT1)

T3 (key, fkeyT2)

I want to get all the rows from T3 that are linked to rows in T2 that are linked to rows in T1 with a given name.

I figure I'll need at least 2 JOIN's; I've got the first JOIN I think:

```
SELECT *
FROM T3 INNER JOIN T2
ON T3.fkeyT2 = T2.key
```

I figure I'll need to take these results and do another JOIN with T1 but I'm not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM t3 INNER JOIN t2 ON (t3.fkeyT2 = t2.key)
          INNER JOIN t1 ON (t2.fkeyT1 = t1.key)
 WHERE t1.name = 'Foo'
```

Comment: What about the WHERE clause (i.e. WHERE t1.name = 'Foo')?  Does that just go after the second JOIN statement?

Comment: @Brendan - Added a WHERE clause

Comment: You can also join back to the same table again like: SELECT * FROM course AS courseStuff INNER JOIN prerequisite AS prereqStuff ON (courseStuff.classId= prereqStuff.classId) INNER JOIN course AS prereqCourse ON (prereqStuff.prereqClass = prereqCourse.classId) WHERE   courseStuff.courseName = "Calculus"

Comment: I think this would be an Oracle example:
SELECT "c"."courseName", "p"."courseName"
FROM"course" "c",
      "prerequisites" "x",
      "course" "p"
WHERE "c"."courseNumber"="x"."courseNumber"
AND "x"."prerequiteCourseNumber" = "c"."courseNumber"